# Powershell script causing overflow

Tags: sql-server, xml, powershell

I am running the following Powershell Script against a list of SQL Instances to return Instance information, including users and roles.  I want to use Powershell to do this as I'm collating the data and will import into another system which will do some analysis.

I created the following script which creates an XML file output for each instance found.  The script works great (yes, it's probably clunky and an awful way to do this, but I'm learning so please feel free to give me a shove in the right direction), however for one of the servers with a few hundred SQL logins I get an overflow message appear on screen, the XML file is not closed correctly and as a result I can't import the results into my analysis system.

I would like either:

Ideas on what could be causing the overflow.  For reference, the output XML that crashes out is 2.5MB in size, with approx 39,000 lines in the XML output before the overflow occurs

[OR]

Another way to get this output - CSV is an option but I don't know enough how to output this - can anyone provide tips?

Thank you in advance

```
#Input file is a plain text file with the name of each of the instances listed in it
$InputFile="C:\Tasks\SQL\Permissions\in\Instances.txt"
$OutputFolder="\\networkdrive\sharedfolder\"

Function GetDBUserInfo($Dbase)  
 {  
 if ($dbase.status -eq "Normal")  # ensures the DB is online before checking
    {$users = $Dbase.users | where {$_.login -eq $SQLLogin.name}   # Ignore the account running this as it is assumed to be an admin account on all servers
foreach ($u in $users)  
{  
    if ($u)  
    {   
        $XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Login")
            $XmlWriter.WriteElementString('DBName', $dbase.name)
            $XmlWriter.WriteElementString('LoginName', $SQLLogin.name) 
            $XmlWriter.WriteStartElement('Login_Roles')
            $DBRoles = $u.enumroles()   
            foreach ($role in $DBRoles) 
            {
                    $XmlWriter.WriteElementString('Role', $Dbase.name)
            } 
            $XmlWriter.WriteEndElement()#Login_Roles
            #Get any explicitly granted permissions
            $XmlWriter.WriteStartElement('Login_Permissions')
                $XmlWriter.WriteElementString('Instance', $svr.name)
                $XmlWriter.WriteElementString('DBName', $dbase.name)
                $XmlWriter.WriteElementString('LoginName', $SQLLogin.name) 
                foreach($perm in $Dbase.EnumObjectPermissions($u.Name))
                {
                    $XmlWriter.WriteElementString('Permissions', $perm.permissionstate.tostring() + " " + $perm.permissiontype.tostring() + " on " + $perm.objectname.tostring() + " in " + $DBase.name.tostring())
                }  
            $XmlWriter.WriteEndElement() #Login_Permissions
        $XMLWriter.WriteEndElement() #Login
    } # Next user in database  
   }  
   #else  
   #Skip to next database.  
 }  
}

#Main portion of script start  
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") | out-null  #ensure we have SQL SMO available

foreach ($SQLsvr in get-content $InputFile)  # read the instance source file to     get instance names
{  
$svr = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") $SQLsvr  
        #Cycle through each instance and write the instance information to the file

#Output file is base folder for each of the text files (which will be named for the instance)
$OutputFile = $svr.name
$OutputFile = $OutputFolder+$OutputFile.Replace("\", "-")+".xml"

# get an XMLTextWriter to create the XML
$XmlWriter = New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter($OutputFile,$Null)

# choose a pretty formatting:
$xmlWriter.Formatting = 'Indented'
$xmlWriter.Indentation = "4"


# write the header
$xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument()

# set XSL statements
$XLSPropText="type='text/xsl' href='style.xsl'"
$xmlWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", $XSLPropText)

# create root element "instances" and add some attributes to it
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Root")

$XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Instance")
$XmlWriter.WriteElementString("SQLInstance", $svr.name)
$XmlWriter.WriteElementString("SQLVersion", $svr.VersionString)
$XmlWriter.WriteElementString("Edition", $svr.Edition)
$XmlWriter.WriteElementString("LoginMode", $svr.loginmode)
$XmlWriter.WriteEndElement #instance

$SQLLogins = $svr.logins  


foreach ($SQLLogin in $SQLLogins)  
{
    #Iterate through each login, writing the details into the login details
    #$XmlWriter.WriteComment("Login Details")
    $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Logins")
    $XmlWriter.WriteElementString("InstanceName", $svr.Name)
    $XmlWriter.WriteElementString("LoginName", $SQLLogin.Name)
    $XmlWriter.WriteElementString("LoginType", $SQLLogin.LoginType)
    $XmlWriter.WriteElementString("Created", $SQLLogin.CreateDate)
    $XmlWriter.WriteElementString("DefaultDatabase", $SQLLogin.DefaultDatabase)
    $XmlWriter.WriteElementString("Disabled", $SQLLogin.IsDisabled)

    $SQLRoles = $SQLLogin.ListMembers()
    If ($SQLRoles) 
        { $XmlWriter.WriteElementString("ServerRole", $SQLRoles) }
    else 
        { $XmlWriter.WriteElementString("ServerRole", "Public") }

    If ( $SQLLogin.LoginType -eq "WindowsGroup" ) 
        {   #get individuals in any Windows domain groups
            $XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("WindowsLogins")
            $XmlWriter.WriteElementString("InstanceName", $svr.name)
            $XmlWriter.WriteElementString("Login", $SQLLogin.name)
            try {   
                    $ADGRoupMembers = get-adgroupmember  $SQLLogin.name.Split("\")[1] -Recursive
                    foreach($member in $ADGRoupMembers)
                    { $XmlWriter.WriteElementString("Account", $member.name.tostring() + "(" + $member.SamAccountName.tostring() +")") }
                }
            catch
                {
                #Sometimes there are 'ghost' groups left behind that are no longer in the domain, this highlights those still in SQL
                    $XmlWriter.WriteElementString("Account", "Unable to locate group " + $SQLLogin.name.Split("\")[1] + " in the AD Domain")
                }
            $XmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
            }
    #Check the permissions in the DBs the Login is linked to.
    If ($SQLLogin.EnumDatabaseMappings())  
    {
        $XmlWriter.WriteStartElement('Permissions')
        $XmlWriter.WriteElementString('InstanceName', $svr.name)
        $xmlwriter.WriteElementString('Login', $SQLLogin.name)
        foreach ( $DB in $svr.Databases)   
           {
            try {   
                               GetDBUserInfo($DB)
                }
            catch
                {
                    echo $_.Exception|format-list -force
                }
           } # Next Database  

        $XmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
        }  
        Else  
        {
            $XmlWriter.WriteStartElement('Permissions')
            $XmlWriter.WriteElementString('InstanceName', $svr.name)
            $xmlwriter.WriteElementString('Login', $SQLLogin.name)
            $XmlWriter.WriteElementString('Permissions', 'No Permissions')
            $XmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
        }   
    $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() #End Logins element
    }
}

# close the "machines" node:
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() #root node

# finalize the document:
$xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument()
$xmlWriter.Flush()
$xmlWriter.Close()
```

When running, error message is:

```
OverloadDefinitions
--------------------    
void WriteEndElement()
void WriteEndElement()
```

No other error or message is given.  The file does get written but is incomplete.

Comment: Export-csv will export the content to the csv file. But you need to modify lot of stuffs for making it to csv

Comment: This line you forgot the `()`: `$XmlWriter.WriteEndElement #instance`

Comment: @RanadipDutta, thank you yes I had considered CSV, but would require multiple CSVs created for each machine.  It is an option, but I'd prefer to get the XML output working.

Comment: @BenH, thank you, but the line does exist - the code works great on most servers I point it at, it only fails on a single, specific instance.

Comment: It's not that line doesn't exist, it that it's missing the `()` which will give you the overload definitions.

Comment: Mis-read your message, sorry Ben - thanks for the clarification - I will give that a go.

Comment: Ok, that cleared the overflow.  Thanks - I still get an issue with size limitations, as it's still truncating the file size, however this may be down to limitations with my chosen method.  I'll see if I can come up with an alternative - good learning experience for me!